# Tratamento de exceções em C++

Tags: c++, exceção, c++11

Estou com uma dúvida referente ao tratamento de exceções em C++, a classe `Fracao` abaixo está propositalmente incompleta não possui nem mesmo *setters* ou *getters* e varias coisas foram "deixadas de lado", possui apenas dois atributos e um construtor, sendo que caso o denominador receba zero, será lançada uma exceção dentro do construtor.

O código funciona perfeitamente, o que gostaria de saber é se é possível fazer, não apenas o lançamento da exceção dentro do construtor/método da classe, mas também o tratamento da mesma, ou seja tirar os blocos `try` e `catch` da `int main`, e tratá-lo em outro lugar evitando que toda vez que eu precise criar um objeto qualquer (do tipo `Fracao` nesse caso) tenha que criá-lo dentro de um bloco `try`, seguido de um `catch`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

class Fracao
{
private:
    int numerador;
    int denominador;

public:
    Fracao(int numerador, int denominador);
};


Fracao::Fracao(int numerador, int denominador)
{
    this->numerador = numerador;

    if(denominador != 0)
        this->denominador = denominador;
    else
        throw "Impossivel dividir por zero";
}

int main()
{

    try
    {
        Fracao f1(1, 0);
    }
    catch(const char* msg)
    {
        cerr << "Erro: " << msg << endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cerr << "Erro desconhecido\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tratar em que lugar?

Comment: @bigown Onde seria normalmente feito o tratamento em um programa em C++? Meu objetivo seria não precisar utilizar try catch para todo objeto criado na main.

Comment: E aí seria tratado onde? Normalmente é feito onde precisa ser feito. Se quer fazer algo diferente, tem que justificar.

Comment: "não possui nem mesmo setters ou getters": javismo ? Em C++, pelo meno em minha experiência, as classes possuem os membros que precisam ter, não existe muito essa preocupação com "setters" e "getters"

Comment: @JoséX. Foi apenas uma forma de dizer que a classe é simples, e para nos atermos somente ao problema, inclusive agradeço seu comentário e concordo com você.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem algumas soluções possíveis, até mesmo não usar exceção. Se a construção do objeto tem um contrato que gera uma exceção quando a criação falha você tem que capturar a exceção e decidir o que fazer.

Note que se isso é considerado um erro de programação e nada deve ser feito você pode deixar sem tratar a exceção ou tratar de forma genérica em apenas um lugar. E esse lugar provavelmente seria a função `main()`. É o caso que parece estar sendo feito. Eu não faria diferente. Em uma aplicação mais complexa que chama outras funções há uma grande chance que eu não faria diferente. Só daria uma mensagem de erro um pouco melhor, registraria em *log* ou algo assim. OU seja, capture a exceção o mais longe possível de onde ocorreu. No caso não dá para ir muito longe que tudo ocorre na `main()`.

Se quer fazer algo específico e tentar resolver a situação (só deve capturar exceções que pode resolver a situação) aí tem que capturar a exceção no local que ela pode ser gerada. Aí é para capturar o mais perto possível que faça sentido.

O que pode fazer para facilitar é criar uma função para manipular o erro e chamá-las ao invés de tratar para todo lado. Isso só é válido se o tratamento é sempre o mesmo.

Claro que aí **talvez** a classe deveria melhor e não precisa disso tudo, mas isso é apenas uma suposição, depende muito do caso. Também tem motivos para não fazer isso.

Se quiser fazer a função seria algo assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class Fracao {
private:
    int numerador;
    int denominador;
 public:
    Fracao(int numerador, int denominador);
};

Fracao::Fracao(int numerador, int denominador) {
    this->numerador = numerador;
    if (denominador != 0) this->denominador = denominador;
    elsethrow "Impossivel dividir por zero";
}

Fracao HandleExceptionFracao(int numerador, int denominador) {
    try {
        Fracao f(numerador, denominador);
        return f;
    } catch (const char* msg) {
        cerr << "Erro: " << msg << endl;
    } catch(...) {
        cerr << "Erro desconhecido\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    Fracao f1 = HandleExceptionFracao(1, 0);
}
```

Veja ["funcionando" no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TcOt5z). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/depwbnjt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Fraction.cpp).

Dá até para fazer uma função genérica que sirva para criar qualquer objeto e cuidar da exceção sempre da mesma maneira. Mas ainda acho que de acordo com o exemplo da pergunta o erro é de programação e o tratamento deveria ser generalizado.

[Seria interessante ler sobre exceções no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50). A maioria não é para o C++, mas a maioria dos conceitos são universais. Bem poucos programadores sabem usar ou entendem para que serve uma exceção e como (não) se deve tratá-la.

Comment: Achei muito interessante sua resposta, e o link que você passou tem umas discussões interessantes, sobre por quê/quando usar ou não exceções, vou conferir. Muito obrigado novamente

Answer (score 0):

Você pode imitar o que outras linguagens de programação fazem, como por exemplo Java, onde existe uma interface `Trowable`, todas as exeções lançadas no Java devem implementar essa interface, então a máquina virtual se encarrega capturar todas as exceptions, então em C++ você faria o seguinte:

Declarar sua classe de Exception que vai servir de base para que seja sempre capturada;

```
class RunnableException {
private:

public:
    virtual std::string getMessage() =0;
};
```

Criar uma classe específica para lançar a exceção do denominador inválido;

```
class ValorInvalidoException : public RunnableException {
private:
    std::string message;

public:
    ValorInvalidoException(std::string message) {
        this->message = message;
    }

    std::string getMessage() { 
        return this->message;
    };
};
```

Ao invés de lançar um const char*, você deverá lançar um objeto;

```
Fracao::Fracao(int numerador, int denominador)
{
    this->numerador = numerador;

    if(denominador != 0)
        this->denominador = denominador;
    else
        throw ValorInvalidoException("Impossivel dividir por zero");
};
```

Use um único try-catch envolvendo toda sua função main;

```
int main() {
    try {
        //faca seu codigo do main normalmente
        Fracao f1(1, 0);
        try {

        } catch (ExcecaoEspecifica e) {
            //coloquei esse try catch aqui só para exemplicar o uso de um outro try
            //ele não tem nada haver com a captura do denominador errado
        }
        Fracao f2(2, 0);
    } catch(RunnableException re) {
        //esse catch vai pegar o denominador errado
        std::cout << t.getMessage() << std::endl;
    }
}
```